# comment_notification_text filter for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, notifications

Is there a way to add  the [`comment_notification_text`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_notification_text/) filter to a custom post type? I'm trying to send a custom email when a comment is left on a custom post type

I am currently using this filter:

```
add_filter( 'comment_notification_headers', 'set_mail_html_content_type', 10, 2 );
```

**UPDATE WITH COMMENT_POST HOOK**

```
function notify_postauthor_comment($comment_id) {

$comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
$post_ID = $comment->comment_post_ID;
$author_ID = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_ID );
$user_info = get_userdata($author_ID);
$email = $user_info->user_email;
$pTitle = $comment->post_title;
$cAuthor = $comment->comment_author;
$cContent = $comment->comment_content;
$cUrl = get_comment_link( $comment_id );

$to = $email;
$subject = 'Your Post,'.$pTitle.', just received a comment!' ;
$headers[] = 'From: email@email.com';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';

ob_start(); 

include("template/email_header.php");
?>

<p>Congrats! You just received a new comment from <?php echo $cAuthor; ?> on your post:</p>
  <p><?php echo $pTitle; ?></p>
  <p><strong>Comment:</strong><br>
    <?php echo $cContent; ?></p>

<?php 
include("template/email_footer.php");
$message = ob_get_contents();
$message = stripslashes($message);
ob_end_clean();

//return $message;

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

}

add_action('comment_post', 'notify_postauthor_comment', 11, 2);
```

Comment: have you try to fire `comment_notification_text` with a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `comment_notification_text` you will get comment notification text and comment ID.
To check the post type you need to get the post associated with comment and then you can check for post type

#### Example (*Read the inline comments*):

```
function custom_notificaion($notify_message, $comment_id) {
    $comment_obj = get_comment($comment_id); //Get comment object
    $comment_post = get_post($comment_obj->comment_post_ID); //Get post object
    
    //Check if it is your post type
    if (isset($comment_post->post_type) && $comment_post->post_type == 'your-post-type') {
        return __('Custom message here', 'text-domain'); //Return the custom message here
    }
    
    return $notify_message; //Return default message for rest of the posts
}
add_filter('comment_notification_text', 'custom_notificaion', 10, 2);
```

Comment: thanks, the other option i found was to use the comment_post hook to work across the board

Comment: Glad to help! I wonder how did you managed using `comment_post` hook. It also return the comment ID only!

Comment: see updated orginal question, guess I used a workaround by just sending an email via wp_mail